# php & mysql please select an other date- message is not appearing

Tags: php, mysql

I have two issues and both are linked.  First, "already booked - please select another date" is not appearing, if two clients select the same product (pg_no) and date (Date).  These fields are  UNIQUE CONSTRAINT.
Second, when data is inserted or submitted localhost shows complete address 
    http://localhost/lstcomp/index.php?note=submitted. But when  it fails the localhost shows only : http://localhost/lstcomp/

```
<?php
//connecting string
include("dbconnect.php");
//assigning
$name  = $_REQUEST['Name'];
$tele  = $_REQUEST['Tele'];
$city  = $_REQUEST['City'];
// UNIQUE CONSTRAINT   
$pg_no = $_REQUEST['pg_no']; //product
$date  = $_REQUEST['Date']; //date



//checking if pg_no and Date are same 
$check = mysqli_query($db_connect, "SELECT * FROM lstclient WHERE pg_no='{$pg_no}', Date='{$date}'");

{
    echo "Already booked  please select another date<br/>";
}
//if not same then insert data
 else
{
    $query = mysqli_query($db_connect, "INSERT INTO lstclient(pg_no,Name,Tele,City,Date) VALUES('$pg_no','$name','$tele','$city','$date')") or die(mysql_error());
}
mysqli_close($db_connect);

// messaging 
if ($query) {
    header("location:index.php?note=failed");
} else {
    header("location:index.php?note=success");
}

?>
```

Comment: Try to re-indent your code because there is no "if" statement before you call echo, there are only brackets.

Comment: If your query fails it calls `die(mysql_error());` which exits your code. So `header("location:index.php?note=failed");` is never called (also the messages are swapped).

Answer (score 2):

There are a few problems:

1. The file fails to parse because of the dangling `else`; it's not paired with an if-statement.

   ```
   {
       echo "Already booked  please select another date<br/>";
   }
   //if not same then insert data
   else
   {
       $query = mysqli_query($db_connect, "INSERT INTO lstclient(pg_no,Name,Tele,City,Date) VALUES('$pg_no','$name','$tele','$city','$date')") or die(mysql_error());
   }
   ```

   It looks like you're intending to use the result from your SELECT statement (`$check`), however...
2. The SELECT statement is invalid; WHERE clauses are separated with AND or OR, not commas.
3. When inserting the row into the database table, you're dying on `mysql_error` when you've been using the `mysqli` extension.
4. You're vulnerable to SQL injection attacks; if `pg_no` happened to be `'; DELETE FROM users; --`, as an example, your user table would be deleted. You're already using the `mysqli` extension, so use parameter binding and prepared statements. [Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)

Comment: I started to write a full answer about all the things that are wrong in the OP code, then I got bored. I'm actually relieved you did it for me !